# Overhead due to AOP logging

Tags: spring-boot, logging, aspectj, spring-aop, execution-time

I am planning to log the execution time of all methods for a REST API. To accomplish this, I use AOP as follows:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
@ConditionalOnExpression("${aspect.enabled:true}")
public class ExecutionTimeAdvice {
  @Around("@annotation(TrackExecutionTime)")
  public Object executionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object object = point.proceed();
    long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info("Class Name: " + point.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + ". Method Name: " + point.getSignature().getName() + ". Time taken for Execution is : " + (endtime - startTime) + "ms");
    return object;
  }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class MessageService {
  @TrackExecutionTime
  @Override
  public List<AlbumEntity> getMessage() {
    return "Hello message";
  }
}
```

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TrackExecutionTime {}
```

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But there is a performance overhead by using AOP. There is a lag in the service response time around more than 200ms, i.e. performance overhead.

What efficient ways are there to implement the execution time logging? Can I use AspectJ for better efficiency? Or there any alternatives to AOP? Can we use AOP in a more efficient way?

Comment: Witch version of `spring-boot` are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 3.2.2 version of spring boot

Comment: Can you support your claim by proof? I measured your aspect with 1,000 calls, logging to the Spring Boot console. The total execution time for an empty method was 80 ms, i.e. orders of magnitude faster than 200 ms per call. I think, you are either measuring the wrong thing or maybe logging to a super slow database synchronously. Besides, why are you manually creating a complex log message and not just logging the joinpoint together with the execution time?

Comment: But actually, `log.info(point + " - execution time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms")` is still 80 ms for 1,000 calls in total. Your bottleneck is certainly not Spring AOP, it is something else, maybe logging as such. You can easily test that by temporarily adding the timing and logging statements to that method manually. The difference in execution time should be barely measurable compared to the AOP solution. Switching from proxy-based Spring AOP to native AspectJ might speed up things, too, but AOP is not the problem in this case.

Comment: OK, I quickly measured execution time for timing and logging directly in the otherwise empty method and without the aspect. 40 ms (compared to 80 ms with Spring AOP) for 1,000 calls, i.e. the AOP overhead is 40 ns (nanoseconds) per call on my old laptop from 2017, logging to the IntelliJ IDEA console and scrolling. With native AspectJ the overhead should basically go down to close zero, but that is optimising the wrong part of the application, if you lose 200 ms per call elsewhere, e.g. in the logging framework configuration itself. That would not go away when logging with another technology.

Comment: Follow the answer that you have and check if it is better than custom implementation that you have written. This is what I supposed to give as an answer.

Comment: @krigaex.. I'm planning to use AspectJ with compile time weaving for Java 17 version. I'm unable to find the proper aspectj compiler maven plugin. Can you please provide some samples regarding the same ?

Comment: https://github.com/dev-aspectj/aspectj-maven-plugin. CTW is a good option, but I am curious why you do not select LTW like most users. For timing that could be advantageous, because you can simply omit it without recompilation if you do not need it, by simply restarting your application with different command line.

Comment: You also did not react to my comments at all, explaining that not AOP is the problem, if logging takes 200 ms instead of just a few ns.

Comment: @krigaex ..  Earlier I did performance testing from two different datacenters. So, there was a huge lag .. Right now tested with same datacenter .. Now I can see 4 to 5ms lag. So, in my case the lag is not from AOP side , it's with two diffrent datacenters. Thanks a lot for ur explanation..

Comment: I thought so. Next time, please measure and compare the right things first, before you waste time trying to optimise the wrong thing. I am glad you found out what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include Micrometer, Prometheus, and Spring Boot Actuator you may reduce the 200+ms overhead. My guess is the 200+ms overhead is due to logging. [This](https://mehmetozkaya.medium.com/monitor-spring-boot-custom-metrics-with-micrometer-and-prometheus-using-docker-62798123c714) article gives a good description of using the `@Timed` annotation to measure public method execution time. Timer information such as maximum and total execution time and number of events is presented when you hit the actuator/promethius endpoint. You would derive the average from the total and number of events.